# Best way to assign pre-defined methods based on a string

Tags: dictionary, go, methods

I am trying to have an array of objects that all have the same member properties and a single method, however each object will have a slightly different method. I am struggling in finding the best way to assign the method to the instance based on another field, which is just a string. For example, I have the object

```
type pet struct {
    breed   string  // cat, dog, or cow
    name    string
    goodboy bool
    speak   func()
}
```

and then I have the methods

```
func (p *pet) woof(){
    fmt.Println("woof")
    p.goodboy = true
}

func (p *pet) meow(){
    fmt.Println("meow")
    p.goodboy = true
}

func (p *pet) moo(){
    fmt.Println("moo")
    p.goodboy = true
}
```

I can instantiate a pet and assign speak to the method easily enough with `spot.speak = spot.woof`. However, I am pulling in the pets from an XML document and storing them in an array. Ideally, I want to loop through all the pets from the XML doc and assign the speak method, and then later be able to call on any `speak()` method for any object in the pets array. Initially I thought of creating a map, but you can't store receivers in a map of functions. This was my thought process for something like how it should work:

```
for _, p := range petsFromXML{
    var tempPet pet
    tempPet.breed = p.breed
    tempPet.name = p.name
    tempPet.goodboy = false
    tempPet.speak = tempPet.speakMap[p.breed]
    pets = append(pets, tempPet)
}
```

but obviously this does not work. I have already started thinking about various different workarounds and I am just wondering what the best way of going about this would be.

Comment: That's pretty much it - you have a map that either defines a function to put into a `func` field, or you have a map that defines a type to use for each kind of value in place of the generic `pet` type.

Comment: Your `pet` type has no `speakMap` so `tempPet.speakMap` cannot work, but lets say it has one, then you're not initializing it, so `tempPet.speakMap[p.breed]` as well would not work. Maybe something like this? https://play.golang.com/p/scJUe9SgVpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
type pet struct {
    breed   string  // cat, dog, or cow
    name    string
    goodboy bool
}

func (p *pet) speak() {
   funcMap[p.breed](p)
}

func woof(p *pet){
    fmt.Println("woof")
    p.goodboy = true
}

var funcMap=map[string]func(*pet){}
```

If you really want to use function pointers:

```
type pet struct {
    breed   string  // cat, dog, or cow
    name    string
    goodboy bool
    speak   func()
}

func woof(p *pet){
    fmt.Println("woof")
    p.goodboy = true
}

var funcMap=map[string]func(*pet){}

var p pet
p.breed="cat"
p.speak=func() { funcMap[p.breed](&p) }
```

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would be to have a map of an

```
map[AvailableFunc]func c() {}
```

where

```
type AvailableFunc string 

const (
Func1 AvailableFunc = "Func1"
)
```

That way it would be more strongly typed as compared to just the string.